# Should C# locked image always be unlocked

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a function that has an image as input.

As my computation depends on several pixels, i cannot directly work on this locked input image, so i use another result image, that i also lock for faster bitmap access.

At then end of my function I unlock both the images.

```
  //...
  //..
  LockedInput.UnlockBits();
  LockedResult.UnlockBits(); // its the image "Result" locked.
return Result;
}
```

What I wonder since the input image isn't returned by this function; should I still unlock it ?. I'm not sure if it will already be released by c# garbage collection. The program doesnt seam to hang if I markout the LockedInput.UnlockBits()  However i'm not sure if it is OK to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Locking bits" means that the object cannot arrange the bits/pixels for bulk access but has to keep them optimized for individual pixel access. Since you don't care about the pixels anymore, you don't care about their representation either. And .Net isn't going to arrange those pixels when it can simply discard all of them. So, unlocking isn't necessary.